# Only build and check model

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a model in ILOG CPLEX written in OPL. I want to run all the semantic checks (in particular all the `assert` statements). I do not want to produce any output files or solve the model.

Judging by the summary of the execution process explained in the [doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_ideref_proces_what.html), I would want to only execute stages 1-3.

Is there a way to do this from the IDE? Or does it need an *.ops file or scripting with OPL script in a main block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in documentation you should have a look at Browse in

IDE and OPL > CPLEX Studio IDE > IDE Reference > The Graphical User Interface > Menu commands and equivalent toolbar buttons

This action is available in the IDE and what it does:

> "Builds or rebuilds the model tree of the data structures defined in
>   the active model or project to allow browsing the project in the
>   Problem browser without solving it.
>
> You can click the arrow next to the button and select the file to
>   browse from the contextual menu."

If you prefer to use flow control and scripting and your model is only preprocessing, constraints and postprocessing you can add

```
main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  writeln("ok");
}
```

which won't call solve

Comment: For future reference: the documentation for CPLEX 12.10 (current version)  explains the command __Browse__ [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_gui_menu_run.html).